# Different results using python 2.7.6 idle as editor

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-idle

Trying to check whether a number is perfect or not and using python 2.7 IDLE as editor I noticed that when I asked in the same script ,that if both numbers (6 and 28) are perfect numbers the result was True, False, the first one was True and second not. But when I asked only the second one that is, only number '28' the result was True. I can't understand the reason.

```
p=[1]

def isPerfect(n):
    for i in range(2,n-1):    
        if n%i == 0:
            p.append(i)
        if n == sum(p):
            return True      
    return False


print 'number 6 is perfect ?', isPerfect(6)

print 'number 28 is perfect ?', isPerfect(28)
```

Comment: Your function preserves state (the `p` variable).
What have you done so far to try and fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are editing the value of p, but are not clearing it before the next call to `isPerferct()` and hence the values of the previous call is still in the list p, which causes the problem. If you print the value of p after the calls, you will understand the problem.

```
p=[1]

def isPerfect(n):
    for i in range(2,n-1):    
        if n%i == 0:
            p.append(i)
        if n == sum(p):
            return True      
    return False


print 'number 6 is perfect ?', isPerfect(6)
print p    # [1, 2, 3]

print 'number 28 is perfect ?', isPerfect(28)
print p    # [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 7, 14]
```

To fix it, either declare p inside the method, or re-initialize p with just [1] at the beginning of the method.

```
def isPerfect(n):
    p = [1]
    for i in range(2,n-1):    
        if n%i == 0:
            p.append(i)
        if n == sum(p):
            return True      
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring p as a global variable, declare it within your function.

```
def isPerfect(n):
    p=[1]
    for i in range(2,n-1):    
        if n%i == 0:
            p.append(i)
        if n == sum(p):
            return True      
    return False
```